# Python list function generates 1 extra list

Tags: python, list, python-2.7

```
def randomly_pokemon_select_function():
    from random import randint
    import linecache

open_pokedex=open("pokedex.txt","r")

p1_p1=list()
p1_p2=list()
p1_p3=list()
p2_p1=list()
p2_p2=list()
p2_p3=list()
player1_pokemons=list()
player2_pokemons=list()
pokemon_selection=(randint(1,40))
p1_p1.append(linecache.getline("pokedex.txt", pokemon_selection).split())
pokemon_selection=(randint(1,40))
p1_p2.append(linecache.getline("pokedex.txt", pokemon_selection).split())
pokemon_selection=(randint(1,40))
p1_p3.append(linecache.getline("pokedex.txt", pokemon_selection).split())
pokemon_selection=(randint(1,40))
p2_p1.append(linecache.getline("pokedex.txt", pokemon_selection).split())
pokemon_selection=(randint(1,40))
p2_p2.append(linecache.getline("pokedex.txt", pokemon_selection).split())
pokemon_selection=(randint(1,40))
p2_p3.append(linecache.getline("pokedex.txt", pokemon_selection).split())
player1_pokemons.append(p1_p1+p1_p2+p1_p3)
player2_pokemons.append(p2_p1+p2_p2+p2_p3)
open_pokedex.close()
print player1_pokemons
print player2_pokemons
return player1_pokemons,player2_pokemons
```

This code works fine but it seems it generates one extra list. The outputs look like this:

[**[**['Geodude', '40', '80', 'Rock', 'Fighting'], 
          ['Raichu', '60', '90', 'Electric', 'Normal'], 
          ['Golem', '80', '120', 'Rock', 'Fighting']**]**]

The strong parenthesis are extra and I couldn't find which line generates that extra list.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You build 3 lists of lists, `p1_p1,`p1_p2`and`p1_p3`; each is a list containing another list, because you append the result of`str.split()` to these.

Each one looks like this:

```
[[datum, datum, datum, datum, datum]]
```

You then concatenate those lists togeher using `+` and *append* them to `player1_pokemons`, already a list object. Rather than append, *just make that your list*:

```
player1_pokemons = p1_p1 + p1_p2 + p1_p3
```

or instead of appending to separate `p1_p1`, `p1_p2`, etc. lists, append directly to `player1_pokemons`. You can do so in a loop:

```
player1_pokemons = [
    linecache.getline("pokedex.txt", randint(1, 40)).split()
    for _ in range(3)]
player2_pokemons = [
    linecache.getline("pokedex.txt", randint(1, 40)).split()
    for _ in range(3)]
```

Note that the `linecache` module already opens and reads the file for you, you don't need to open the file yourself.

Answer (score 0):

When add the lists in the append method you are creating a list of lists and then appending that onto a list.